# Right way to use Reactor as a task executor

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am looking at [documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference) a way to use Reactor as a task executor. I want to submit some tasks, parallelize it then wait for it termination like the ThreadService, sample bellow:

```
final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
pool.submit(() -> {sleep(200);System.out.println(1);});
pool.submit(() -> System.out.println(2));
pool.submit(() -> System.out.println(3));
pool.submit(() -> System.out.println(4));
pool.submit(() -> System.out.println(5));
pool.submit(() -> System.out.println(6));
pool.submit(() -> System.out.println(7));
pool.submit(() -> System.out.println(8));
pool.submit(() -> System.out.println(9));
pool.submit(() -> System.out.println(10));

pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
pool.shutdown();
```

I only got that when collecting the results to a list

```
final List<Integer> result = Flux.range(1, 15)
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .map(n -> {
        // simulating heavy task
        sleep((long) (Math.random() * 100));
        return n;
    })
    .sequential()
    .collectList().block();
System.out.println(result);
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first please keep in mind that your blocking `map` is fine **only** because you are running it in an elastic `Scheduler` (could have been `parallel()` too).

if you don't care about the result and want to block on the termination, you can use `.blockLast()` (it will return the last `n` computed, but you can ignore that.

if you want to compose further on the chain, like starting another process, you can chain any flavor of `then`, which will return a `Mono` that represents the task termination (dropping the data events).